# what does this yii framework line of code mean?

Tags: php, yii

I am new to php and the yii framework. I have started developing simple a application using the yii framework and I see this in lot of places:

```
yii::app()
```

Could someone explain to me what does this syntax means and is it a PHP-specific way of programming?

Comment: The initial Y is normally seen in upper case, btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thats calling the static method `app` on the class `yii`.

[Scope Resolution Operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php)

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the Yii framework but I can tell you that `yii` is a [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), and `app()` is a [static method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) (or function) of that [class](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

> Static properties cannot be accessed through the object using the arrow operator ->.
>
> Calling non-static methods statically generates an E_STRICT level warning.

For example, since `app()` is a *static* method, this is **not** allowed:

```
$yiiInstance = new yii();
$yiiInstance->app();  // triggers E_STRICT warning because app is static
```

Answer (score 1):

It is standard PHP syntax for calling a static funcion:

Its just calling the function `app` form the class `yii`, statically.

Answer (score 1):

The double colon is s 'scope resolution operator'. http://www.phpbuilder.com/manual/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 0):

Whilst the other answers are correct the *Yii::app()* static method is for getting the instance of the application.

It's the object oriented version of a global variable. Almost all modules, components and extensions are linked to the application instance, hence why it is so common. For example if you wanted to register a script you would use the *clientScript* application component *Yii::app()->clientScript*

Comment: This is the correct answer. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.application